# Naviagting XML from AutoTask in server-side NetSuite

Tags: javascript, xml, netsuite

I'm working on an integration between someone's NetSuite account and their AutoTask account. It receives data from AutoTask, creates records within NetSuite, and then passes some of that data back into AutoTask. The way AutoTask seems to work, I have to remove a chunk of the received XML, make changes to it, and then POST that updated chunk right back into the system otherwise it erases anything that's not included. So, after receiving the XML as text, I use the function nlapiStringToXML() to convert it to an XML object:

```
var xmlObj = nlapiStringToXML(xmlString);
```

I did some testing with the data to get the needed data. Here's a sample of the received XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <queryResponse xmlns="http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/">
            <queryResult>
                <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
                <EntityResults>
                    <Entity xsi:type="Ticket">
                        <id>54606</id>
                        <UserDefinedFields>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>3rd Party Case Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Check in Text Single Line</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Escalation Case Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Additional Max Hours</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Additional Pay Rate</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Check In</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Check In MultiLine</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Check in Numeric</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Check Out</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Closing Notes</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN HD Name You Closed With</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Manager On Duty</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Max Hours/Devices</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Pay Mode</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Pay Rate</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Provider Cell Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Provider Name</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Return Tracking #</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Scheduled Date and Time</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Status</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField><UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Total Amount</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FN Work Order ID</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>FOLLOW-UP NEEDED</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Kaseya Alert ID</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Kaseya Ticket ID</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Netsuite Case Internal Id</Name>
                                <Value>-2</Value>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Netsuite Case Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>New HW SN Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Old HW SN Number</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>RMA</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>Sales Order</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                            <UserDefinedField>
                                <Name>SB OLO?</Name>
                            </UserDefinedField>
                        </UserDefinedFields>
                        <AccountID xsi:type="xsd:int">000</AccountID>
                        <AllocationCodeID xsi:type="xsd:int">00000000</AllocationCodeID>
                        <CreateDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-04-12T08:49:54.323</CreateDate>
                        <CreatorResourceID xsi:type="xsd:int">29682898</CreatorResourceID>
                        <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Integration Testing</Description>
                        <DueDateTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-04-13T08:47:00</DueDateTime>
                        <IssueType xsi:type="xsd:int">17</IssueType>
                        <LastActivityDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-04-12T08:50:11.1</LastActivityDate>
                        <Priority xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Priority>
                        <AssignedResourceID xsi:type="xsd:int">00000000</AssignedResourceID>
                        <AssignedResourceRoleID xsi:type="xsd:int">00000000</AssignedResourceRoleID>
                        <Source xsi:type="xsd:int">8</Source>
                        <Status xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Status>
                        <SubIssueType xsi:type="xsd:int">282</SubIssueType>
                        <TicketNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">T00000000.0000</TicketNumber>
                        <Title xsi:type="xsd:string">Integration Testing</Title>
                        <FirstResponseDueDateTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-04-12T12:49:54.323</FirstResponseDueDateTime>
                        <ResolvedDueDateTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-04-13T08:49:54.323</ResolvedDueDateTime>
                        <ServiceLevelAgreementID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ServiceLevelAgreementID>
                        <Resolution xsi:type="xsd:string"/><PurchaseOrderNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <TicketType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</TicketType>
                        <ChangeInfoField1 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <ChangeInfoField2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <ChangeInfoField3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <ChangeInfoField4 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <ChangeInfoField5 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <TicketCategory xsi:type="xsd:int">3</TicketCategory>
                        <ExternalID xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                    </Entity>
                </EntityResults>
                <EntityResultType>ticket</EntityResultType>
                <Errors/>
                <EntityReturnInfoResults>
                    <EntityReturnInfo>
                        <EntityId>54606</EntityId>
                        <DatabaseAction>None</DatabaseAction>
                        <DuplicateStatus>
                            <Found>false</Found>
                            <MatchInfo/>
                            <Ignored>false</Ignored>
                        </DuplicateStatus>
                        <Message/>
                    </EntityReturnInfo>
                </EntityReturnInfoResults>
            </queryResult>
        </queryResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I need is the "Entity" element, and in my testing this was the way to grab what I needed:

```
var eObj = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("Entity")[0];
```

However, that results in the following error when executed server-side:

```
Java class "org.apache.xerces.dom.DeepNodeListImpl" has no public instance field or method named "0"
```

Using NetSuite's debugger to examine this and figure it out, it looks like I get a test string instead of an XML object:

```
eObj ==> {string} org.apache.xerces.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@239776f9
```

I have go the following route to get the chunk I need:

```
var eObj = xmlObj.childNodes.firstChild.childNodes.firstChild.childNodes.firstChild.childNodes.firstChild.childNodes.firstChild.getNextSibling().firstChild;
```

I know NetSuite has XML navigation methods, but I've found them to be unreliable. The above method assumes that everything will always be in the same exact position, and I don't like that since if the values returned change with new or removed values, this will break. Especially considering that I need to pull up the UserDefinedFields element and run through the children and update a handful of them. I was intending to run through, check to see if the "Name" matched certain values, and then add a "Value" tag to the "UserDefinedField" element for matches. But given this structure I'm being presented with (which defies what gets displayed about the object structure in the debugger), I'm baffled as to how I can iterate through these child elements, find what needs to be updated, and get the task complete. This is what I had planned to use, which seems to work in a browser console:

```
for (var i = 0; i < eObj.getElementsByTagName("UserDefinedField").length; i++) {
    if (eObj.getElementsByTagName("UserDefinedField")[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].innerHTML == "FIELD_NAME") {
        var vObjArr = eObj.getElementsByTagName("UserDefinedField")[i].getElementsByTagName("Value");
        if (_tools.isEmpty(vObjArr) || vObjArr.length == 0) {
            var vObjA = xmlObj.createElement("Value");
            var vObjB = xmlObj.createTextNode("VALUE");
            vObjA.appendChild(vObjB);
            eObj.getElementsByTagName("UserDefinedField")[i].appendChild(vObjA);
        } else {
            eObj.getElementsByTagName("UserDefinedField")[i].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].innerHTML = "VALUE";
        }
    }
    if (/* additional values checks here*/) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm left clueless as to how to alter this in the face of the new reality presented to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var eObj = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("Entity")[0];
```

use this:

```
var eObj = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("Entity").item(0)
```

Just because the return object is a DeepNodeListImpl and the class implement a methode **item(int index)** that  returns the node at the specified index . It also has a **getLength()** that returns the length of the node list.. See the [doc here](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeepNodeListImpl.html) for more explanation.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This works wonderfully. But I had to go a completely different route involving extracting xml text using regular expressions. I needed to convert that extracted chunk of xml back into a string to slip into some response xml, but the method nlapiXMLToString() ignores the chunk because apparently it's an "element" and not a "document". But still thank you very much, as I know I'll need this again.

Comment: I am glad it will help you. I did not really test the all thing, i don't have the environment that is why i could not be more specific, then i am still sorry for that.